# Difference between Identity link type in activiti

Tags: scala, activiti

I am using activiti for my application.Here,when i'm assigning a task to the particular user sometimes the identity link type is as 'PARTICIPANT' and sometimes it is like 'CANDIDATE".In the modeler,for the user task i'm assigning the variable to assignee as

```
  assignee = ${user}  //In my case user = "kermit" or customUser
```

If the identity link type is 'participant' it has the process instance id.With the process instance id i'm getting the task as null.Is there any way to get the task.

```
 val processEngine: ProcessEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine()
 val taskService: TaskService = processEngine.getTaskService
 val task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(idl.getProcessInstanceId).singleResult()
```

Can anyone please tell me how the identity link type will be generated during runtime as 'candidate' or 'participant'.

Answer (score 2):

'candidate' is added when the user task has the 'candidate groups' or 'candidate users' set.

'participant' is set for a user that is the assignee, the task owner or the person who has completed the task (not necessarily the same as assignee/owner for the Activiti API).

It is also possible to add a custom user/group with these identityLink types to a task, using the *taskService.addUserIdentityLink* and *taskService.addGroupIdentityLink* method. The types are in the *org.activiti.engine.task.IdentityLinkType* class.